# How to correct error DatabaseException (near ")": syntax error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

error DatabaseException(near ")": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE my_table (
I/flutter (21754):             _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
I/flutter (21754):             name TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (21754):                 address TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (21754):                     comments TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (21754):                             sigURL TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (21754):                                                         selfpicURL TEXT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (21754):
I/flutter (21754):                             hi INT NOT NULL,
I/flutter (21754):                                                     time TEXT NOT NULL,

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {

static final _databaseName = "MyDatabase.db";
static final _databaseVersion = 1;

static final table = 'my_table';

static final columnId = '_id';
static final columnName = 'name';
static final address = 'address';

static final comments = 'comments';
static final sigURL = 'sigURL';

static final columnAge = 'hi';

static final  selfpicURL = 'selfpicURL';

static final  createdTime = 'time';

DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

static Database? _database;
Future<Database> get database async {
if (_database != null) return _database!;
// lazily instantiate the db the first time it is accessed
_database = await _initDatabase();
return _database!;
}

_initDatabase() async {
Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
return await openDatabase(path,
version: _databaseVersion,
onCreate: _onCreate);
}

Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnName TEXT NOT NULL,
            $address TEXT NOT NULL,
           $comments TEXT NOT NULL,
            $sigURL TEXT NOT NULL,
           $selfpicURL TEXT NOT NULL,

           $columnAge INT NOT NULL,
            $createdTime TEXT NOT NULL,

                        
                        
            
          )
          ''');
}


Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
Database db = await instance.database;
return await db.insert(table, row);
}


Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllRows() async {
Database db = await instance.database;
return await db.query(table);
}


Future queryRowCount() async {
Database db = await instance.database;
return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table'));
}


Future<int> update(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
Database db = await instance.database;
int id = row[columnId];
return await db.update(table, row, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
}


Future<int> delete(int id) async {
Database db = await instance.database;
return await db.delete(table, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite SQL parser does not support trailing comma before the end parenthesis

Instead of (at the end of your statement)

```
  ...
  $createdTime TEXT NOT NULL,
)
```

do

```
  ...
  $createdTime TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table $tableTodo ( 
  $columnId integer primary key autoincrement, 
  $columnTitle text not null,
  $columnDone integer not null)
''');
```

if you look carefully in the last line **$columnDone integer not null** it has no comma like the other 2 top lines, that's the problem in your code.

[for more info](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't support trailing commas. Try removing the comma of your last statement about creating a table. for example

if you are writing like this;

$createdTime TEXT NOT NULL,

try instead;

$createdTime TEXT NOT NULL